# NordVPN app won't do anything

Tags: 22.04, nordvpn

So I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I installed the Nord app curl in terminal. I see the app, but when I click the icon nada. I did `nordvpn login` in terminal. It launches my browser with the link. I sign in. It will say "Great – you’re in! You’ve successfully logged in.". If I click on continue in the browser nothing happens. If I try `nordvpn connect` in terminal it says "You are not logged in". What is going on and how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: [these are the instructions](https://support.nordvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/20196094470929-Installing-NordVPN-on-Linux-distributions) for using NordVPN with Ubuntu. Is this what you followed?

Comment: Yep and all I got is "You are not logged in". That's after I do nordvpn connect after getting you're all set on the login screen.

Comment: In which event, have you considered contacting NordVPN directly through their [support site](https://support.nordvpn.com/hc/en-us/)